# Binding ObjectProperty<Node> to Node's children

Tags: java, javafx

I have some ObjectProperty in my class and I don't know how can I bind it to Node's children.
My code:

```
public class Base extends Parent {

    private ObjectProperty<Panel> panel;
    private final HBox foundation;

    public Base() {
        panel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        foundation = new HBox(20);
        // ???
        getChildren().add(foundation);
    }

    //------Properties below

    public final ObjectProperty<Panel> panelProperty() {
        return panel;
    }

    public final void setPanel(Panel value) {
        panelProperty().setValue(value);
    }

    public final Panel getPanel() {
        return panelProperty().getValue();
    }

}
```

I want to have an automatic system working like that:

Setting panel property value -> adding the value (node) to foundation's children

EDIT:
I'm talking about adding the node via FXML, like that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Base xmlns:fx="gui">
    <panel>
        <Panel/>
    </panel>
</Base>
```

Comment: This doesn’t really make sense. Your `ObjectProperty` is a single node. The pane’s children is a whole collection of nodes. You can’t bind a collection to a single value.

Comment: @James_D I'm not sure if you understood me correctly. I wanna make sure that when I add/remove a node (panel property), the node will be automatically added/removed from the foundation.getChildren() list

Comment: When you add/remove a node to what? You can’t add or remove nodes from `panel`, it just represents a single node, not a collection. So what is the user of the class adding/removing them from?

Comment: @James_D when I add a node in FXML file, like in the latest EDIT. I wanna make <Panel/> visible (that means I wanna add it to foundation.getChildren() list)

Comment: This still makes no sense. If you set it up like this, you’d only be able to have a single `Panel` in the FXML file, but you’re writing code that supports a whole set of child nodes.

Comment: @James_D I want to have only one Panel, but don't want to allow other node types. Could you please explain me how can I do this better?

Comment: “I want to have only one panel”; that makes more sense, it’s just completely contradictory to what you said earlier about adding and removing nodes. Just add a listener to `panel` and call `foundation.getChildren().setAll(...)` with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want `foundation` to contain a single element, which is the current value of `panel`, just add a listener to `panel`:

```
public Base() {
    panel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    foundation = new HBox(20);
    panel.addListener((obs, oldPanel, newPanel) -> {
        if (newPanel == null) {
            foundation.getChildren().clear();
        } else {
            // Assumes Panel is a subclass of Node:
            foundation.getChildren().setAll(newPanel);
        }
    });
    getChildren().add(foundation);
}
```

Note that there's no real reason to expose an observable property for `panel` here, unless you have some other pressing need to actually observe it and respond to changes externally to the class (which seems unlikely). You could simplify the whole thing to:

```
public class Base extends Parent {

    private final HBox foundation;

    public Base() {
        foundation = new HBox(20);
        getChildren().add(foundation);
    }


    public final void setPanel(Panel value) {
        if (value == null) {
            foundation.getChildren().clear();
        } else {
            foundation.getChildren().setAll(value);
        }
    }

    public final Panel getPanel() {
        if (foundation.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            return null ;
        }
        return (Panel) foundation.getChildren().get(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: What if I'd like to have Panel and let's say Table? Should I store reference to them and when I set a new instance remove the old one from the list?